# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component when using Hooks

Tags: reactjs

I am not able to use React hooks. I have 4 components:

- `ComponentA`
- `componentC`
- `componentE`
- `componentF`

I need to pass `value` to `componentF` directly from `componentA` without having to pass from `componentC` and `componentE`. All components are in a single tree.

```
    // componentA
    import React from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    import ComponentC from "./components/ComponentC";
    export const UserContext = React.useContext();
    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
            <UserContext.Provider>
                <ComponentC  value={'My message'}/>
            </UserContext.Provider>

        </div>
      );
    }
    export default componentA;

    // componentF
    import React from 'react';
    import UserContext from '../App';
    function ComponentF() {
        return (
            <div>
                <UserContext.Consumer>
                    {
                        user => {
                            return (
                                <div>you are {user}</div>
                            )
                        }
                    }
                </UserContext.Consumer>
            </div>
        )
    }
    export default ComponentF;
```

It is giving an error when I am trying to use context:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Comment: well, what does `ComponentC` look like?

Comment: componentA contains ComponentC, ComponentC contains ComponentE, componentE contains componentF linearly.

Comment: thats great, but that doesn't help fix your issue. You have hooks somewhere where you aren't supposed to. render that part plz

Comment: import React from 'react';
import ComponentE from "./ComponentE";

function ComponentC() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ComponentE />
        </div>
    )
}
export default ComponentC;

Comment: import React from 'react';
import ComponentF from './ComponentF'

function ComponentE() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ComponentF />
        </div>
    )
}
export default ComponentE;

Comment: can you please post the code where you are using hooks? this error is thrown related to that.

Comment: i am not able to use value passed from parent to last child, i,e componentF, i have passed value from componentA via componentC

Comment: omg. you aren't listening to what im saying. You have an exception saying `Invalid hook call.` you are using a hook. and using it incorrectly. Can you show me where that is? all I see right now is components that just render jsx and have no state. Does one have a state via a hook?

Comment: I didn't use hook anywhere in the code.  while i try to run this much code only, it renders me with these errors

Comment: Added a solution, check it out. You are using the hook - React.useContext. You should be using React.createContext.

Comment: Thanks,,, now i am facing this issue

Comment: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is that you are using `React.useContext()`

You should be doing:

```
export const UserContext = React.createContext();
```

To pass to the child components of Component A, you can do it like this:

```
<UserContext.Provider value={100}>
     <ComponentC  .../>
</UserContext.Provider>
```

And instead of using UserContext.Consumer, you can get the value using `React.useContext` inside the component body of ComponentF.

```
// componentF
    import React from 'react';
    import {UserContext} from '../App';
    function ComponentF() {
      const value = React.useContext(UserContext);
        return (
            <div>
                ....
                {value} // which will be equal to 100
            </div>
        )
    }
    export default ComponentF;
```

Comment: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: value is coming as undefined

Comment: import {UserContext} from '../App'; 
Edited. Check now

Comment: Thanks it works,, it have to be import as named import